# how to multiply a matrix by its transposed?

Tags: matlab

I want to multiply a matrix by its transposed in order to knwo if it verify Q<sup>t</sup>Q=I.

Yet when I compute it on matlab I get something strange using a concept I'm not aware of: `conj(x)`.

- Therefore, how to multiply a matrix by its transposed?

Here is the code I tried:

```
>> syms x
>> A=[cos(x) -sin(x);
sin(x) cos(x)]

A =

[ cos(x), -sin(x)]
[ sin(x),  cos(x)]

>> A'*A

ans =

[ cos(conj(x))*cos(x) + sin(conj(x))*sin(x), sin(conj(x))*cos(x) - cos(conj(x))*sin(x)]
[ cos(conj(x))*sin(x) - sin(conj(x))*cos(x), cos(conj(x))*cos(x) + sin(conj(x))*sin(x)]
```

Comment: Have you already looked in matlab help? What remains unclear?

Comment: @Alex.S Yes, I did, but to my mind a<sub>1,1</sub> should have been 1 for instance. And instead it gives me the complex conjugate...

Comment: users of matlab are often scientists, more scientist than programmer, and they may find that a matlab specific support site is more beneficial e.g. http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com  Also people there are more mathematical and scientific and may be better candidates to answer such a mathematical question.  Many left tried going from matlab to python but found what scientist described to me as a "lack of support" and switched to matlab so I guess a matlab forum is better for a scientist than SO(and def better than SU).

Comment: @barlop okay, too bad :(

Comment: @Marine1 too good you mean. There is a lot of support for scientists stuck with matlab, less so with python. Where that support is shouldn't matter to you. You shouldn't think negatively if you got an answer that makes sense and points you in the right direction.  I can assure you that a bunch of PhD scientists on a matlab forum could solve your matlab problem quicker than they can pick their nose or quicker than they can make small talk.

Comment: @Marine1 Do you know if `x` is real? From your use of `Q` (as opposed to `U`), I am guessing you are talking about orthogonal matrices and so `x` is real?

Comment: @barlop, OK, have to ask (for context): how long do you think it takes a bunch of PhD scientists to pick their nose?  And you don't qualify that in your comment, so don't say it depends on how much practice they have.  Also, you refer to a bunch of scientists, but just one nose.  Are you assuming a number of related scientists with a genetic abnormality, co-joined at the nose, or is the nose a single organ the scientists are growing in the lab.  Nose-picking time could be assumed to be different if the nose isn't attached to their face.  Inquiring minds want to know.  :-)

Comment: Use `.'` instead. `'` is complex conjugate transpose. `.'` is normal transpose.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but given the community bot is intent on bumping it, might as well answer it.

The reason MATLAB is giving you `conj` in the output is because you are using the complex conjugate transpose operator, `'` (a.k.a `ctranspose()`).

Because this is symbolic math, MATLAB does not make any assumptions as to whether `x` is real or complex, so it must leave `conj()` in the output - for real the function does nothing, for complex it will take the conjugate.

If you use `.'` instead, this is the regular matrix transpose (a.k.a `transpose()`). As a result MATLAB doesn't add any complex conjucate calls to the output because it ignores the contents of the array when doing the transpose.

```
>> A'*A
 
ans =
 
[ cos(conj(x))*cos(x) + sin(conj(x))*sin(x), sin(conj(x))*cos(x) - cos(conj(x))*sin(x)]
[ cos(conj(x))*sin(x) - sin(conj(x))*cos(x), cos(conj(x))*cos(x) + sin(conj(x))*sin(x)]

>> A.'*A
 
ans =
 
[ cos(x)^2 + sin(x)^2,                   0]
[                   0, cos(x)^2 + sin(x)^2]
```

---

Note: `cos(x)^2 + sin(x)^2 == 1`, so `ans == [1 0;0 1] == I`.